# How can i make sure the form is clean and repainted ?, some Timage remains on the screen even after i empty the bitmap

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I have a program which allows the user to click on a directory and the program will  start loading all the images there and shows them on the screen and the user can view them by scrolling down
Now here is the issue, after the program loads a directory, if the user clicks on another directory, after loading the new directory some times there are **remains** of the previous images on the screen (`Form`) !, now here is the thing, if i for example try focusing another controller(component) and then i click on the form, **the remains will get cleaned!** so it seems the problem lies with the fact t**he form is not repainted** or something like that!
Here is what you need to know about my program :
1-What i said happens in `Fullscreen`
2-I am in `FMX` and i use `TImage`
In the end i should mention that i have already tried using `form1.invalidate;`, which cleans the remains of something like an image resize but doesn't work on the image remains (**when i say remains i mean a whole picture not residues**)

**Update 01:**
Honestly it was fairly hard to reproduce this problem, i tried my best and i think this example kinda shows what i am talking about, **i think the issue arises from the fact that i am doing my loading and cleaning in another thread, because i was not able to reproduce this problem in a single thread application**
Here is the test case code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Generics.Collections,
  FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  mImageList: TList<TImage>;
  mSwitch: boolean;

implementation
uses
  Threading;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  cImage: TImage;
  I: Integer;
begin
  mImageList := TList<TImage>.create;
  mSwitch := false;

  for I := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    cImage := TImage.Create(nil);
    cImage.Parent := Form2;
    mImageList.Add(cImage);
  end;

  Form2.FullScreen := true;
  timer1.Interval := 3000;
end;

procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

begin

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
    var
      I: Integer;
      heightSum: single;
      path: string;
    begin
      if not(mSwitch) then
        path := 'images\1\1 ('
      else
        path := 'images\2\2 (';

      heightSum := 0;

      for I := 0 to mImageList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        mImageList[I].Bitmap := nil;
      end;

      for I := 0 to mImageList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        mImageList[I].Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + (i + 1).ToString + ').jpg');
        mImageList[I].Width := mImageList[I].Bitmap.Width;
        mImageList[I].Height := mImageList[I].Bitmap.Height;
        mImageList[I].Position.X := Form2.Width / 2 - mImageList[I].Width / 2;
        mImageList[I].Position.Y := heightSum;
        heightSum := heightSum + mImageList[I].Height;
      end;

      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin
        end);
    end).Start;


  mSwitch := not(mSwitch);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I removed the delphi-xe tag since you clearly are not using that version, which predates FMX. I added the firemonkey tag. Now, could you please add a [mcve] so that we can see code that demonstrates the problem. Without this the question will be closed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I tried to create a minimal example, for one thing i noticed i couldn't recreate my problem in a single thread application so i tried a multithread approach like my original program, and i "kinda" got a similar result, hope this shows where i went wrong.

Comment: Your asumption is correct. The problems you are expiriencig are caused by unproper use of multithreading. All the code that is interacting tih any viasual FMX components should be executed from withing anonymus method you pass to`TThread.Synchronize`.

Comment: @SilverWarior But the real program works with a lot of images ! since the loading would take too long, i try loading the first couple of images in the main thread and then i will load the rest in the anonymous thread, if i try to them all in the `Tthread.synchronize` , it will cause lag

Comment: By the way why are you loading all of the images from your folder into a signle TImage component? That is a bad design and could lead to you running out of memory. Delphi comes with an example which shows how to create a image preview program. I don't remember what it is called. But if my memory serves me correctly another goal of that example is demonstrating the use of gesture movements for scrolling through images.

Comment: @aliahmadi Why do you need to pre-load the images. Couldn't you just load them right before they are being shown. That is how Windows Excplorer Works when you using preview feature in folder with images.

Comment: @SilverWarior My program is infact a manga viewer which sometimes gets scrolled very fast and the images have heights close to 30000 pixels ! which i have to turn into smaller pieces any way the point is i need to load a lot of image for a smooth experiance when scrolling

Comment: @aliahmadi I see. Then I suggest you try loading your images into multiple TBitmap's first and then assign those that needs to be visile from TBitmap ti TImage. I'm not sure but I believe FMX TBitmap was made thread-safe in one of the recent Delphi versions. Which means you could probably load your images into these TBitmap classes in the background thread. I'm not on my development machine so I can't thest this out.

Comment: The fact that you want to improve the performance of your program does not mean that you can simply ignore the rules!

Comment: So generally you guys suggest i do the load and assign using bitmaps which is thread safe, and finally in the main thread i use maybe 2 or 3 TImage which kinda rotate around each other while loading the necessary bitmap, is this what you mean ?, by the way, is there any way to make TImage thread safe or any other way to fix this issue i'm having ?, thanks.

Comment: @aliahmadi: the issue is that FMX/VCL is not threadsafe to begin with. While technically it is possible to write a multithreaded GUI, the ramifications are complex and not really worth the effort. Just do the loading in a separate thread and use a producer/consumer model.